# In C, when prompting a user input string, an undesirable output results

Tags: c, string, user-input

Can someone please explain why the proceeding block of code always results in "Sorry, that's not one of the choices," even when the user types 'Classical' or 'Jazz'?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
    char c[20];

    printf("Hey! I hear you like music! What type do you like? (Classical/Jazz/Rock) ");

    gets(c);

    if(c == "Classical" || c == "classical")
        printf("Classical music is great.");
    else if(c == "Jazz" || c == "jazz")
        printf("Jazz is awesome!");
    else
        printf("Sorry, that's not one of the choices.");

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: strcmp() will help you out.

Comment: You should not use `gets`.  Try using `scanf` or `fgets`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, you have to use [`strcmp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) to compare strings:

```
if(strmp(c, "Classical") == 0 || strcmp(c, "classical") == 0)
    printf("Classical music is great.");
else if(strcmp(c, "Jazz") == 0 || strcmp(c, "jazz") == 0)
    printf("Jazz is awesome!");
else
    printf("Sorry, that's not one of the choices.");
```

If `a` and `b` are two C strings, `a == b` doesn't do what you think it might. It checks whether `a` and `b` point to the same memory rather than checking whether they consist of the same characters.

In your case, `c == "Classical"` etc will *always* evaluate to false.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(c == "Classical" || c == "classical")
```

Above is invalid string comparison. Use `strcmp` instead as below:

```
if(0 == strcmp(c, "Classical")) { // if c and "Classical" are equal
    printf("equal!\n");
}
```

Click [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) for reference page.

Answer (score 0):

You must compare them as strings.

```
 if(strcmp(c,"Classical")==0 || strcmp(c,"classical")==0)
        printf("Classical music is great.");
    else if(strcmp(c,"Jazz")==0 || strcmp(c,"jazz")==0)
        printf("Jazz is awesome!");
    else
        printf("Sorry, that's not one of the choices.");
```

Answer (score 0):

In C you can't compare string pointer directly, as that really just compares the actual pointers and not what they point to.

And as string literals are always pointers, and an array can decay to a pointer, what you are doing is comparing the pointers.

In fact you can't even be sure that two otherwise equal string literals will be equal when comparing their pointers. The compiler may store the strings in different locations even if they are the same.

As explained by others, in C you have to use the [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) function to compare strings.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I got ahead of myself when I discovered user-input and now realize I need to learn things about c-strings and pointers.